# Two unexplained downvotes on "Triangled printing" question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

Some time ago a posted a simple Python script: [Triangled printing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95567/triangled-printing). It contained an example of the desired output, worked and was in my opinion fully on-topic. It still got two down votes, so what was wrong with that? Were the down votes just miss-clicks or maybe the question was just plain boring or too trivial? Tell me so that I will improve my future question-posting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I had to speculate, I would guess that it was this statement in Rev 1:

> On mobile I am not able to indent the code.. sorry

Especially since indentation is significant in Python.  The code was just unintelligible the way it was originally posted.

Comment: This makes sense, next time I will take some time to format even on mobile, thanks for being so fast finding the issue :)

Comment: And the down-voters probably did not even comment thinking "If he does not even bother to format, I'll not bother to comment"

Comment: This cannot be stated enough: proper code formatting (especially with languages like Python and Perl) is very important to helping others understand the structure and operations of your code.

Comment: @EBrown Mea culpa, Still there should be a way to format code without losing 5 minutes on mobile... My code was also on the short side, imagine manually entering spaces for 80-100 lines... :O

Comment: The Android and iOS apps both have a block-indent button in the editor. You can also switch to the full desktop version via a link at the bottom of the site.

Comment: @200_success the apps' editor (especially android) still has some minor and major bugs with the cool buttons

Comment: @200_success I found the magic buttons, thanks! You never stop learning.